# Regex to match mostly alphanumeric paths

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I tried creating a regular expression to verify path names for a filesystem API I write using GridFS.

My current RegEx `^[A-Za-z0-9\-\[\]()$#_./]*$` can fulfill this criteria:

- Allow `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `-[]()$#_./`

However it doesn't meet these additional criteria:

- First Character has to be `/`
- There mustn't be any occurrence of multiple `/` in a row.

**Questions:**

- Can anybody help me fix my RegEx?
- Are there any possible issues for using my criteria for path names? (Did I miss anything important?)

Comment: You probably want to avoid .. in the path as well for example /one/../two

Comment: @SQLHacks yeah, I guess I will path.normalize that (node.js provides a method to make an absolute path out of it), thanks for bringing that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about the path criteria, but regarding the RegExp, pretty simple:

```
^\/(?!\/)([A-Za-z0-9\-\[\]()$#_.]|(\/(?!\/)))*$
```

`\/(?!\/)` means a slash `/` not followed by a slash `(?!\/)`. I used it twice, once as the first character, and again as one of the possible matches after the first character.

Comment: Seems to work quite well, but `/` [needs to be escaped](https://www.regex101.com/#javascript) like this `\/`. Will accept once I can, but you should edit that.

Comment: Actually, it only needs to be escaped if you create your RegExp object with a literal. if you use `new RegExp('/(?!/)')` you don't need any escaping.

Comment: Really? That websites tells me it's not valid. Also I think you can leave out one pair of round brackets in the last addition.

Comment: Actually, if you use a literal, you're correct, you need to escape the slash. But if you use the `new RegExp()` constructor and pass it a string, you'll need to escape all the back-slashes in the string! ;)

Comment: @RobRaisch - Ha, you're right... didn't notice that :-) I'd just edit the "literal" escape.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could address your requirements. To enforce the first character is `/`, simply add that after the `^`.

`^\/[A-Za-z0-9\-\[\]()$#_./]*$`

To not allow consecutive slashes, you should remove it from your character set, and think of the set as a portion of the path. Portions would be separated by a slash. So the final regex would be:

`^\/([A-Za-z0-9\-\[\]()$#_.]\/?)*$`